# Tensorflow download

Tags: python, tensorflow

when I try to download Tensorflow, I get these errors. Can you help me please?

```
ERROR: astroid 2.2.5 requires typed-ast>=1.3.0; implementation_name == "cpython", which is not installed.
ERROR: tf-models-official 2.6.0 has requirement tensorflow>=2.5.0, but you'll have tensorflow 2.4.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: tensorflow-text 2.6.0 has requirement tensorflow<2.7,>=2.6.0, but you'll have tensorflow 2.4.1 which is incompatible.
ERROR: lvis 0.5.3 has requirement matplotlib>=3.1.1, but you'll have matplotlib 3.1.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: apache-beam 2.32.0 has requirement avro-python3!=1.9.2,<1.10.0,>=1.8.1, but you'll have avro-python3 1.10.2 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: How are you installing tf? Is Python >3.6 installed? Is `python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv` installed? Instead of struggeling with the installation, you can easily use the [docker image](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/docker).

Comment: From error, you have Tensorflow 2.4.1, but you need Tensorflow 2.6.0. Follow the instructions mentioned on the [Tensorflow doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip). Install `pip install tensorflow` which downloads latest Tensorflow version.